# How do you solve the second order differential equation of velocity for position using separation of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I start with the well known velocity function $$v = v_i + at$$
which means $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx_i}{dt} + \frac{d(\frac{dx}{dt})}{dt}t$$,
multiplying both sides by dt and integrating
$$\int_{x_i}^{x_f}dx = \int_{v_it_i}^{v_it_f}{x_i}+ \int d(\frac{dx}{dt})t$$

What am I missing to get to the end result of the well known position equation $$x_f = x_i + v\Delta t + \frac{1}{2}a\Delta t^2$$ I am especially having trouble with the last variable with getting the acceleration component correctly as well as figuring out what the integration limits are for that component.

v is velocity and x is position

Answer (score 0):

$$v={dx\over dt} \rightarrow vdt=dx$$

Now we can substitute in the equation for velocity....

$$vdt=dx \rightarrow (v_i+at)dt=dx$$

Integrate on both sides...

$$\int_{t_i}^{t_f}(v_i+at)dt=\int_{x_i}^{x_f}dx$$

Which gives us the kinematic equation you wanted...

$$\Delta x=v_i\Delta t+{1\over2}a\Delta t^2$$

Comment: I know this method of getting the position function but I am wondering how come you cannot do it the way I did it in my question -- using separation of variables

Answer (score 0):

> I start with the well known velocity function $$v = v_i + at$$
> which means $$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx_i}{dt} + \frac{d(\frac{dx}{dt})}{dt}t$$

No, $v_i$ is a starting condition, so it's just a number, not a derivative.

One more point,
$$\frac{d(\frac{dx}{dt})}{dt}t$$
is usually written as
$$\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$$

> What am I missing to get to the end result of the well known position equation $$x_f = x_i + v\Delta t + \frac{1}{2}a\Delta t^2$$

This equation is for constant acceleration, so
$$
\int {d^2 x\over d^2 t} t dt = {d^2 x\over d^2 t}\int t dt
$$
because the acceleration (usually just written as $a$) is constant.

> I am especially having trouble with the last variable with getting the acceleration component correctly as well as figuring out what the integration limits are for that component.

You're integrating just the $t$ part, which gives you the $\frac12 t^2$. Similarly that initial velocity is constant, so the integral is just the integral of a constant.

Comment: I know they are both constants, but the derivative can be a constant as well. How come the starting condition $v_i$ cannot be written as $\frac{dx}{dt}$? it seems like it can...and how come the acceleration cannot be written as ${d^2 x\over d^2 t}$ and have dt multiplied and then integrated like I have written